# How to properly write Dispose and Disconnect functions for the class that have TcpClient and SslStream objects

Tags: c#

How to properly write Dispose and Disconnect functions for the class that have `TcpClient` and `SslStream` objects?

Should I do smth like this

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    // release unmanaged memory

    if (disposing)
    {
        // release other disposable objects
        if (_sslStream != null)
        {
            _sslStream.Dispose();
            _sslStream = null;
        }

        if (_tcpClient != null)
        {
            _tcpClient.Close();
            _tcpClient = null;
        }
    }
}
```

or smth like this

```
public void Disconnect()
{
    _tcpClient.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    _tcpClient.Client.Disconnect(false);
    _tcpClient.GetStream().Close();
    _tcpClient.Close();
}
```

There are a lot of methods in the `TcpClient` class that does Disconnect and Shutdown operations but I don't know which of them should I prefer to add the ability to reconnect to the server via the same object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't using the using keyword?

Comment: @user2202911: `using` is only ok if the object has a lifetime within one method call. This object may be created in a GUI and reside there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dispose` looks fine for me.

In `Disconnect` I'd also do a `Dispose` and

1. followed by a recreation
2. or recreate upon next usage.

Comment: Dispose on what object? _sslStream?

Comment: Instead of `Disconnect` simply `Dispose` or `Close` and then recreate the objects.